# Method to return a List to populate DataTable from a query containing inner join

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I created a JSF project in Eclipse using primefaces components and data persistence with Hibernate. In this project, for each model class, there are at least two views (xhtml pages), one DAO class and a controller class. In DAO there is the following method to return a list of objects that I use to populate a DataTable. Below I put the snippets of DAO and xhtml page I am using to populate the DataTable.

TextoBaseDAO.java

```
public List<Textobase> listar()
{       
    List<Textobase> listTextobase = null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_textobase inner join tbl_disciplina on tbl_textobase.disciplina_textobase = tbl_disciplina.id_disciplina";

    try
    {
        this.manager.getTransaction().begin();
        listTextobase = this.manager.createNativeQuery(query, new Textobase().getClass()).getResultList();
        this.manager.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        listTextobase = null;
        this.manager.getTransaction().rollback();
    }

    return listTextobase;
}
```

TextobaseController.java

```
private List<Assunto> assuntos;

public List<Textobase> getTextosBases() 
{
    this.textosBases = textoBaseDao.listar();
    return textosBases;
}
```

Textobaselist.xhtml

```
<p:dataTable  var="textobase" value="#{textobaseController.textosBases}" id="textobaseTable" rowKey="#{textobase.codigo_textobase}"
     selectionMode="single" selection="#{textobaseController.currentTextoBase}" style="text-align:center" paginator="true" rows="10"
     paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" 
     rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" lazy="true">

        <f:facet name="header">
            Texto Base
            <br/>
        </f:facet>  

        <p:column width="50" headerText="Código" sortBy="codigo_textobase" id="codigo_textobase" filterBy="codigo_textobase" filterMatchMode="contains">
            #{textobase.codigo_textobase}
        </p:column>

        <p:column width="650" headerText="Texto" sortBy="texto_textobase" id="texto_textobase" filterBy="texto_textobase" filterMatchMode="contains">
            #{textobase.titulo_textobase}
        </p:column>
```

It's all working out perfectly so far. But I need to run a query that returns the objects with fields of external tables using inner join to populate the DataTable, including the fields of the outer table too. So the query would look like this:

```
String query = "SELECT ";
   query += "tbl_textobase.codigo_textobase, ";
   query += "tbl_textobase.titulo_textobase, ";
   query += "tbl_disciplina.nome_disciplina ";
   query += "FROM tbl_textobase ";
   query += "inner join tbl_disciplina ";
   query += "on tbl_textobase.disciplina_textobase = tbl_disciplina.id_disciplina";
```

But as I am returning a List of Textobase, the fields of the outer table is not returned in this list. So here's my question:

What changes I should make in the "listar()" method and in my DataTable to return a list including the fields of the outer table and that could populate the dataTable correctly?

Grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things...

```
    listTextobase = this.manager.createNativeQuery(query, 
            new Textobase().getClass()).getResultList();
```

WILL make a mapping to the Textobase class... So the most straightforward solution would be to add a few transient attributes to the class, annotated with @Transient: ie:

```
    private String attribute;        
    ...
    @Transient
    public String getAttribute(){
         return this.attribute;
    }
    ...
```

Next, you might want to do

```
List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>)entityManager
             .createNativeQuery(query).getResultList();
```

So you can iterate on an Object[] list. Next, your Textobase class should have an n parameter constructor, where all of the parameters are instances of Object.class, including the transient attributes. Then you could have something like:

```
    List<TextoBase> result = new ArrayList<TextoBase>();
    for (Object[] o : list){
       TextoBase row = new TextoBase(o[0],o[1],o[2],...);
   result.add(aux);
}
```

Hope this helps. Suerte.